# Matrix rows and columns manipulation with matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a way for a given matrix:

```
k= a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1
   a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 
   a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3
   a4 b4 c4 d4 e4 f4
```

to create two variables that have the values:

```
a=a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4

and

b=d1,e1,f1,d2,e2,f2,d3,e3,f3,d4,e4,f4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = k(:, 1:3)';
a = a(:)';
b = k(:, 4:6)';
b = b(:)';
```

Comment: You could also do `a = reshape(k(:, 1:3)', 1, []))` and `b = reshape(k(:, 4:6)', 1, []))` in one line :)